# acrobat form field validation regular expressions

Tags: javascript, regex, acrobat

Working in Acrobat X and trying to validate a field using a Regular Expression. My problem is that when I use the following in my JavaScript code:

```
var myRegExp = /dog/;
var myTextInput = event.value;

event.rc = true;

if (myTextInput != myRegExp) {
    app.alert("It's a regex why do I need to input '/dog/'! and not just dog");
}
```

entered within the Variable tab of the Text Field Properties dialogue box - it does not see it as a Regular Expression.

That is to say; if I type 'dog' (ignore quote marks) into the live pdf field it gives an error, but if I input '/dog/' (ignore quote marks) into the field it works fine.

My Question: why is my var not being recognized as a Regular Expression.

I had read that the open '/' and close '/' (ignore quote marks) defined a Regular Expression but this does not appear to be case. What am I missing here?

Comment: Should you be using the Validate tab with a custom script? [Example here](http://khkonsulting.com/2012/11/validating-field-contents/).

Comment: hi JakieChiles My error, I meant the Validate tab. Yes I can get get your sample to work but that does not use a Regular Expression. If I substitute the 'AAAA' and 'BBBB' for a Variable Expression var then I get the result I talk of in my question. Thanks for your post though.

Comment: So what is the rest of the code you're using in your custom validation script? You've only posted one line.

Comment: 'code'var myRegExp = /dog/;
var myTextInput = event.value;
event.rc = true;
if (myTextInput != myRegExp)
{
    app.alert("It's a regex why do I need to input '/dog/'! and not just dog");
} 'code'

Comment: Please edit your question to include all of that code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue seems to be that you're testing for equality between a `RegExp` object and a string. Instead, you need to use the `test` method:

```
var myRegExp = /dog/;
var myTextInput = event.value;

event.rc = myRegExp.test(myTextInput);
```

See [MDN for more documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/test).

The following operation is incorrect and will always return `false`:

```
/dog/ == "dog";
```

Comment: JackieChiles, You've made my day! Thanks you.  With a small amend it works a charm.

Comment: Below is the code that works for me. Sorry don't seem to be able to use mini mark down to make this clearer.

var myRegExp = /dog/;
var myTextInput = event.value;

event.rc = true;

if (!(myRegExp.test(myTextInput))) 

{
app.alert("You typed:" + myTextInput + "You need to type dog");
    event.target.textColor = color.red;
}
else
{
    event.target.textColor = color.black;
}